# Dont display post with no content

Tags: plugin-development

In my blog index page I do not want to show posts which has empty content but only title ([How does filter the_posts work?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37686/how-does-filter-the-posts-work)) . I am looking at 'the_post' hook which seems to fire inside the loop . So , I thought if the action hook is fired inside the loop I could check the post content on 'the_post' hook and if it is null continue with the loop . I tried the below :

```
add_action('the_post' , 'rb_test_the_post');

function rb_test_the_post($post){
    if (($post->post_content) == '') { 
        continue;
    }
}
```

This gives me an error in Wordpress  ( "The site is experiencing technical difficulties " and also in my editor as it doesnt see any while or if statement for the continue statement.) . I am not able to understand why the continue statement doesnt work even though the hook is fired inside the loop .Could some one please explain?

Also , how would one achieve this (using a plugin and not the theme as I want the empty posts not to show even when I change theme) ?

Comment: You've changed from `$post` in the function call to `$posts` in the `if()` statement. As far as the function is concerned, `$posts` is an uninitialized variable, and you're using it as though it's an object.

Comment: I changed the code in the if statement  (which I happened to somehow mistype in SE)  but the problem still persists . Get The site is experiencing technical difficulties error .

Comment: I'd recommend [turning on `WP_DEBUG`](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) to see what the actual error is. The "WordPress is experiencing technical difficulties" error is a generic message that usually indicates there's a fatal error somewhere in your PHP code.

Comment: The error is simple your are trying to use continue not within a php loop but within a function, that will not work.

Comment: I feel so stupid thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to do this using a plugin and not theme . Here is how :

```
function my_filter_where($where = ''){
    return $where .= "AND trim(coalesce(post_content, '')) <>''";
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'my_filter_where');
```

Answer (score 0):

The content is a property of the post object, not of the query object.
Use $post or get_post() :

```
  if( '' !== get_post()->post_content ) {
    // do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check the post content is empty or not:

```
if ( "" === $post->post_content )
{
//dont display your post 
 }
else
{
 //your post's code goes here
  the_title();
  the_content();
 }
```